# *ngFor not showing my [object Object] data in Angular View

Tags: angular, typescript, templates, ngfor

I'm trying to iterate over an object returned from the fastAPI backend endpoint in my Angular template. ( my data actually is there, but I can't iterate over it, the only syntax that works with is is when using a JSON pipeline )
and the result is like this in my front end:
**EDIT ( DATA )**

```
{  
"1": { "Id": 1, "ruleData": [], "ruleName": "someName", "testDesc": "", "test": "test", "ruleErrorMessage": "someError" } ,

"2": { "Id": 2, "ruleData": [], "ruleName": "someName", "testDesc": "", "test": "test", "ruleErrorMessage": "someError" } 
}
```

but data doesn't appear, here's my template code

```
 <h5 *ngFor="let smth of analysisResults.someData">
                   testets >>> {{smth}}
</h5>
```

my service code:

```
export class backend{
    backendURL="http://localhost:8000/doSomthing/";
    constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient){}
    requrl: string;
    
    getQuality(text: string){
        this.requrl=this.backendURL+text;
        return this.httpclient.get<AnalysisResults>(this.requrl)
    } 
}
```

my .ts code:

```
constructor(private backend: backendService) { }
  req = new FormControl('');
  analysisResults: AnalysisResults;
  getQuality(reqValue: string) {
    this.backend.getQuality(reqValue)
      .subscribe((data: AnalysisResults) => this.analysisResults = {
          score:(data as any[])['score'] ,
          someData:(data as any[])['someData'] ,
      } ) }
```

my model code:

```
export interface AnalysisResults {
    score?:number;
    someData?:[];
}
```

Comment: please post your data

Comment: do a console.log inside the subscribe to see what is returned by your backend

Comment: @KrishnaKarki I added the data to the post

Comment: @HarisBouchlis Actually the data is there in the template, but the problem is with the iteration

Comment: Your example data is not valid JSON, nor an array.

Comment: @JSmart523 Fixed it's just a typo

Comment: why are you casting the data inside your subscribe? That seems unnecessary as you already use a type in the http request?

Comment: @CharlieV I was just testing if the problem was from there nothing changes when I remove it

Comment: The data shown in your question does not match the interface in your code example. The data looks like a python dictionary and you can type that in Typescript by using the following ```type pythonDict = { [key: number]: { "id": number, "rule data": string[],.... } ```

Answer (score 0):

In the interface you have defined an array for someData without a type. If you cast it to any[] you can use it. Else it will be an empty array because typescript desperately needs a type.

```
export interface AnalysisResults {
  score?:number;
  someData?:any[];
}
```

See the example in stackblitz. If you remove the any type and just leave the array, stackblitz will complain.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bovpdk?file=src/app/app.component.ts